# Select columns with numbers only, no strings

Tags: pandas

I am using the hads dataset. This set contains many entries of households with many variables associated with each household. In these variable columns, many of them are strings denoted with 'variable_info_here' and I want to create a new dataframe with just the variables that contain only numbers. Since there are many variables, I do not know which variables contain only numbers. Is there a quick way to check for this?

Answer (score 1):

To select columns with numbers, try :

```
df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html